# how to manage WebSockets in svelte as a separate service

Tags: javascript, typescript, websocket, svelte

I am creating a chat widget using svelte and using `websocket` for the communication,
the one thing I want to do is keeping the `websocket` code out of the main component.
the code block bellow shows the implementation of `websocket` in my main component where it's being used.

I want to create a separate file named `socket-service` and define all the events there and use as they needed in any component.

```
    //////////////////////////
    /////// Chat.svelte///////
    //////////////////////////

    onMount(() => {
        // startSocket(widgetWindow)
        ws.onopen = () => {
            console.log("socket is on");
        };
        ws.onmessage = (e) => {
            handleRecievedMessage(e);
        };
    });
```

Comment: What is preventing you from doing that?

Comment: actually i don't know how to do  '-'